# Соотнесённость однородных сказуемых с дополнением

Tags: управление, однородные-члены, дополнение

*Ты умеешь складывать, умножать и считать простые проценты.*

Здесь к простым процентам относится только слово "считать". "Складывать" и "умножать" здесь непереходные, однако могут быть спутаны с переходными глаголами, которые имеют прямое дополнение наравне с "считать". Требует ли предложение перестройки?

Comment: Проценты вычисляют. Счёт — начальный уровень знания.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Ты умеешь складывать и умножать числа и вычислять простые проценты.**

Считать проценты – разговорное выражение, в математике оно не применяется. Процент – сотая доля числа, поэтому проценты **вычисляют или определяют**.

Вообще говоря, **лучше  писать коротко, точно и ясно**, а двусмысленностей всякого рода по возможности избегать.

Здесь достаточно было уточнить, что действия производятся **с числами** и использовать **точный термин** для работ с процентами. Тогда и не будут возникать  трудно решаемые грамматические задачи.

Comment: Мне кажется, что имеются в виду простые и сложные банковские проценты: http://real-investment.ru/finansovaja_gramotnost/formula_prostykh_i_slozhnykh_procentov_kak_ehto_rabotae Здесь допустима фраза "расчет простого и сложного процента".

Comment: Так и эти проценты рассчитывают, а не считают, я думаю.

Comment: П.п. **рассчитываются** следующим образом...(Энциклопедия банковского дела и финансов)

Answer (score 1):

Предложение может существовать в такой форме, особенно если контекст позволяет понять смысл. Но перестройка пошла бы на пользу. Можно вынести последний однородный член на первую позицию, либо поставить перед "и" длинное тире, интонационно и визуально отделив последний глагол. Это избавит от двойственности.

Comment: «Ты умеешь складывать и умножать числа и считать от них простые проценты». Вот так, я думаю, сгодится.

Comment: Да, в этом варианте двойственности нет.